# Debugging mixed Delphi (native) and C# code, getting "binary was built without debug information"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, delphi, debugging, debug-symbols

I've got a C# DLL [with native exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/csharpprojecttemplateforunmanagedexports), which is called from some Delphi 2009 code. The Delphi code uses `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to access the exported functions. I'd like to debug the managed part of the code at runtime, but I'm running into trouble.

When I launch the application, the breakpoints appear properly, but fail to be hit.

My current setup is the following:

- C# DLL project in Visual Studio 2010
- Project's debug settings set to "Start external program", pointing at the Delphi executable.
- Enabled unmanaged code debugging is switched off.
- Just My Code is enabled in the debug options (this seems to make no difference)

I've tried enabling unmanaged code debugging, but that causes an error saying "binary was built without debug information". If I continue, all breakpoints are disabled.

When I checked the modules list, the executable shows as having no debug symbols. Delphi doesn't generate a PDB (it can't, since it's a closed-spec proprietary format) but it generates a MAP file instead. I had a look around for MAP-to-PDB converter tools, but it seems there's only a tool for doing the reverse of what I need.

I'm not really interested in debugging the Delphi code from Visual Studio, since I can already do that in the CodeGear Delphi IDE, but is there a way to debug the managed code at runtime in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. The issue wasn't with debug symbols, but rather the type of code being debugged. If you launch an application from your project startup settings, the debugger starts in mixed mode, which requires native symbols to be available in order to catch C# code invoked from native code.

I wasn't able to get Visual Studio to accept the pdb files created by [tds2dbg](http://code.google.com/p/map2dbg/), so I found a workaround. In order to ensure that the debugger launches in managed mode, attach to the process instead of launching it, like so:

1. Debug -> Attach to process...
2. Select the running process.
3. Click the "Select..." button to the right of "Attach to".
4. Select "Debug these code types"
5. Check Managed (v2.0, v1.1, v1.0) for .NET 3.5 or less, or Managed (v4.0) for .NET 4.0 or later. Not sure why v3.5 is excluded from the naming here.
6. Click OK, click Attach.

After this, all breakpoints should work nicely :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a "tds2pdb" you can try to create a .pdb file:
http://code.google.com/p/map2dbg/downloads/detail?name=tds2pdb102.zip

Note: it's not a complete .pdb file (specs aren't available) but at least it is working for stack traces. However, not all symbols (classes, variables, parameters) are exported. But you can always try...

Comment: The Delphi compiler / linker doesn't produce a TDS file.

Comment: Er, the question is about debugging the managed code. This answer is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @Polynomial: Newer version have an option to generate an external debug file (*.tds).

Comment: @AndreasHausladen I'm using CodeGear Delphi 2009. We don't have the option of upgrading, sorry.

Comment: So it turns out TD32 debug info is embedded into the .exe file, but the IDE doesn't support saving it separately. I found a tool that extracts it, and another tool that converts it to a .dbg file, but Visual Studio is refusing to recognise it as a match to the executable.

Comment: Did I misunderstand? I thought you wanted to debug the managed code?

Comment: Yes, I do, but it won't allow me to apply the PDB to the managed DLL until I supply symbols for the executable that hosts it.

Comment: That's odd. I've never come across a debugger like that. Is it that way because it is managed? In any case I would say that my exerience with tds2pdb (to get symbols in Process Explorer stack traces) was not successful.

Comment: Found a solution. Will post it as an answer.